# Interpretación erronea de arrays en el navegador

Tags: javascript

Genero un array con js, y en cuanto a logica lo genera correctamente como lo requiero, pero al mostrarlo en el log, me lo interpreta de la siguiente manera

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando lo despliego, me muestra datos completamente diferentes.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No entiendo por que lo interpreta de esa manera el navegador, o si es algún tipo de error de tiempos de ejecucion en mi function; basicamente me muestra los datos del ultimo array en todos.

Utilizo este codigo para generar el array

```javascript
let arrayData = [];
let arrayGeneral = [];
function genData(posicion){
    arrayGeneral.length = 0;
    let arrayPreguntas = auxPreguntasJson[0].preguntas.split(",");
    let arrayProductos = auxPreguntasJson[0].productos.split(",");
    
    for(let q=0;q<pregSeleccionadas;q++){
        let auxColor = colorRGB();
        
        for(let i=0;i<dataRespuestas.length;i++){
            arrayData.length = 0;
            let respuesta = dataRespuestas[i].respuestas;
            let fecha = dataRespuestas[i].fecha;
            let arrayRespuestas = respuesta.split(',');
            let respPregunta = arrayRespuestas[posicion];
            
            let day = fecha.substring(8);
            
            for(let q=arrayLapsos[0];q<=arrayLapsos[arrayLapsos.length - 1];q++){
                let dia = q;
                if(parseInt(day) == dia){
                    console.log("es igual "+parseInt(day)+"**"+dia);
                    arrayData.push(parseInt(respPregunta)); 
                }else{
                    arrayData.push(0);
                }
            }
            console.log(arrayData)
            arrayGeneral.push(arrayData);
            //console.log(arrayGeneral)
        }
        
    }
    //console.log(dataRespuestas)
    console.log(arrayGeneral);  
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es porque siempre se usa el mismo arreglo.

```
arrayData.length = 0;
```

Con el código anterior solo se reinicia el tamaño del arreglo pero sigue siendo el mismo.

Lo que se debería hacer es crear uno nuevo:

```
arrayData = [];
```